# When typing escape to stop searching, it hides the close dialog

Tags: bug

I'm not sure if there's a way to even tell - maybe it's actually a bug in Chromium...

Right now my son is asleep in my arms so I can't reach the mouse without waking him. So I'm just trying to use keyboard navigation in Chromium 54.0.2840.90 on Arch Linux. To find the links I'm using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>, which mostly works. However, when I went to close a question, I tried to do a find on "off topic", and then I hit <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Rather than just hiding the find dialog, the close dialog *also* went away.

I ended out having to just open the close dialog and then hitting tab several times to get to the form elements. Which *works* but not quite like everywhere else on the page.

Comment: Esc is the shortcut key to close dialogs. Just looks like Chrome doesn't cancel propagation to the page once it's closed the Find dialog.